# Wearable notifications with different styles are identical to the standard

Tags: android, wear-os

According tho the wearable documentation its possible to add extended content to a notification on a wearable (http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html).

However I've tried using BigTextStyle but the resulting notifications are the same size/style/content as if no style at all was used.

In each case the notification is initially displayed with just one line of text:
[image]

And when expanded the version with no style and bit text style is the same:
[image]![image]

If I extend the amount of text into a few lines then in both cases the display is still the same (which is that the

Am I missing something, what is it supposed to look like? Why is there no difference?

I'm trying to get two lines of text displayed on the collapsed notification view and was experimenting with the different styles available to see if that gave that, but I'm not getting any differences even with the expanded notification when I try different styles so I don't see what the point of them is unless my code is incorrect?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("My Title");
notificationBuilder.setContentText("My content");

//   BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
//    bigTextStyle.bigText("My big text style");
//   notificationBuilder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no difference between using a `BigTextStyle` and non-`BigTextStyle` on the main notification on Android Wear devices:

- In collapsed mode, the title is the only thing shown. It will be cut off if it is longer than the available one line
- While in a previous version of Android Wear, if you did not set a `BigTextStyle` then the text would get cut off (and not scroll), it now appears that in expanded mode, both will show the full text, scrolling if necessary

Of course, the big difference currently between using `BigTextStyle` and not is on the phone side: if you don't use it then the text will be limited to one line on the phone. Assuming you want to allow the phone notifications to expand, you should set both the content title and content text as well as the BigTextStyle.

The other two styles (`BigPictureStyle` and `InboxStyle`) have a much more profound impact on how the notifications appear on Android Wear.

NOTE: there is one other recent apparent bug where if you don't set content title / text (and only set the `BigTextStyle` then nothing will display. As content title / text is required for the primary notification, this only affects you if you are building [an additional page](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/pages.html).

Comment: Thanks. Ultimately I would like to get two lines of text appearing in the notification when its in a collapsed state (i.e. something like title and sub title). Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: No, that is currently not possible.

Comment: Is there any way a Wearable app could fake it or present something similar  - i.e. instead of the Mobile app posting a notification instead it sends a message to the wearable app and the wearable app pops up some custom GUI element that covers the wearable screen or a portion of it?

Comment: Anything is possible, but I wouldn't recommend that kind of approach. Do remember that important notifications (those with high priority or include vibrate/sound) are shown in expanded form when they initially come in and turn the screen on.